# Why isn't the following javascript code working? (Crafty.js used)

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie, in crafty as well as js, so pardon me if I might have made very silly errors in the following program.
What is  wrong with the following code? The following code is supposed to create 5*5 matrix where each block would be a 60 pixel high and wide iceblock as stored in iceblock.jpg.

```
window.onload=function()
{
    Crafty.init(500,500);
    Crafty.canvas();
    Crafty.sprite(60,"iceblock.jpg",{block : [0,0]});
    Crafty.c("iceblock",function(){
        init: function(){
            this.addComponent("2D, Canvas, Mouse, block");
            this.w = 60;
            this.h = 60;
        }
    });


};
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            Crafty.e("iceblock").attr({x: i*60,y: j*60})
        }
    }
```

The corresponding HTML code is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="crafty.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assignment.js"></script>
    <title>My Crafty Game</title>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the HTML page, the complete output page is blank.
This is the link to the image.
http://postimage.org/image/ivqfhmjt9/

PS:- Is there a less annoying way to indent our code instead of putting 4 spaces infront of each line? Very time consuming and tedious.

Comment: You can always copy your code into an IDE like Notepad++ or even notepad and then use your tab button on your keyboard to indent your code, and then select it all and copy paste it to SO.

Comment: @h2ooooooo ... thanks....isn't there a code tag or something on so?

Comment: and any idea why the code isn't working?

Comment: @NikharAgrawal Use http://jsbeautifier.com/ to format the code, then paste the code on SO, select it, and press Ctrl + K to prefix four spaces (or press on the code button, `{}`, in the markdown editor).

Comment: Use debugging tools (if one must be named : FiereBug). What are the error messages ?

Comment: I am a newbie and I don't exactly know how to use firebug. Anyways, I installed it and tried using it. Under the Script tag, it's just showing one script that is crafty.js... its not showing assignment.js. Is it weird?

Comment: btw, thanks Rob and Romain for your responses. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, see this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/craftyjs/OkG5rFb3tqo

Or the code here http://jsfiddle.net/cYxeZ/